# java script convert string to integer

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code, the `x` could be a string or so.
I've tried to convert it but my code still won't run.

If I put a number instead of `x` like `usage[1]` or so... it runs ok.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iptable tr').click(function (event) {
    var x = parseInt("$(this).attr('id')");
    alert({{ usage[x] }}); 
  });
});
```

Comment: it should be `var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));`

Comment: plz add convenient chunks  from html file

Comment: @AswinRamesh, you are right. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

`var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));`

sample you can find here

```js
var usage = ["a", "b", "c"];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iptable tr').click(function(event) {
    var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
    alert(usage[x]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="iptable">
  <tr id="0">
    <td> row 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
    <td> row 2 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td> row 1 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for the example but is it not working for me maybe because the flask {{}} thing

Comment: yeah, I had removed that too while answering

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes and use radix while using paseInt

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#iptable tr').click(function(event) {
     var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'),10);
     alert({{usage[x]}}); 
   });
 });
```

Comment: thank you for  your comment, but it is still not working. tried evend this way   var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id')); var y = {{usage}};var z = y[x];alert(  z  );
  still not working

Answer (score 0):

> **Aswin Ramesh**: it should be `var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));`

As **Aswin Ramesh** stated you are using quotation marks incorrect:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#iptable tr').click(function(event) {
     var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
     alert({{usage[x]}}); 
   });
 });
```

This is the correct coding.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding extra quotes

//script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#iptable tr').click(function(event) {
     var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
     alert({{usage[x]}}); 
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how it runs for me!

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#iptable tr').click(function (event) {
            // alert($(this).attr('id'));
            // var x = $(this).attr('id');
            var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'),10);
            var y = {{usage}};
            alert (y[x -1]);
            
       });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var usage = {{ usage|tojson }};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iptable tr').click(function (event) {
        var x = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        alert(usage[x]); 
    });
});
```

The pieces between the `{{ }}` signs are rendered by *Jinja/Flask* on the server before the code every gets to Javascript, so you can't pass `x` *(a variable being generated on the fly in Javascript)* into that syntax... BUT you can pass the **usage** variable (assuming it is an object here) from the Python/Flask code into a Javascript variable using the [**Jinja `tojson` builtin filter**](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#tojson)